# Align divs on the left with css, separating them into groups, without line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I'm looking for a way to align divs on the left, though, keep them divided into groups, without a group breaking the line. The code below comes close but I would like to get the result of the image.

```css
.group {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #008040;
    overflow: inherit;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.machine {
    float: left;
    border-color: red;
    height: 75px;
    width: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

The above code gives me this result (CURRENT):

[image]

But I would like to get this other result (DESIRED):

[image]

It's possible?

Comment: Use of flexwrap can change the output as you desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If showed borders are for reference only you could try setting the outer `div` to `display: inline;`. If you need borders they can be set to the first and the last children with selectors: `.group:first-child` and `.group:last-child`.
Using `float` overrides `inline` but as long as `inline` are aligned like a text, you don't need float.

```css
.group {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #008040;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:5px;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    display: inline;
}

/*
.group:first-child {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}

.group:last-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}*/

.machine {
    /*float: left;*/
    border-color: red;
    height: 75px;
    width: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;   
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, we're very close. The problem is that the "display: inline" makes it very difficult to format (padding, margin, etc).

Comment: @user1872936 you can apply formatting on "subDivs" instead. They are `inline-block`. You can set the margin for `first-child` and `last-child` to set the margin for the group. I know it is a bit ugly, but it's pure CSS ;)